# Twilio-Video Quickstart Issue with new xcode8

Tags: swift, twilio, xcode8

I'm trying to build the Video Quickstart App from Twilio with new Xcode8 Beta. When I try to run this project, I have to convert the code to the new swift syntax.

The problem is that I get more than 100 errors after this.

[image: xcode errors]

Comment: The quickstart hasn't been updated to xcode 8 yet, but I'm sure it will be as xcode 8 becomes more widely used. That's all I can tell you right now, sorry! If you make any progress with errors, do let me know.

Comment: @philnash Hi how to know other user is online or offline .may you have me please?

Comment: @AbecedarioPoint you need to use the reachabilty indicator. Check out the docs here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/chat/reachability-indicator

Comment: @philnash thank you i will try